# Do I need mutex for simple shared memory IPC?

Tags: ipc, mutex, shared-memory

I am currently working on an extremely time-critical application(some sort of control system with RTOS which cares about tens of nanoseconds.

Using shared memory IPC to separate time-critical real-time routine and application routine, I wonder if I need to use mutex or not.

In this case, each shared memory will be sort of one direction channel; One process will write to the shared memory constantly, and another process will keep read the memory for logging and other application services. The application process will not update the shared memory.

In this case, do I need to utilize mutex? Isn't the OS won't let real concurrent access for basic access like simply reading and writing?  If so, could I consider mutex is redundant?

My guess is one process will wait until the other process is reading or writing the memory regardless of the existence of mutex.

Comment: I'd say that depends on whether the writes are atomic for the data size and infrastructure you're on.

Comment: @AKX It would be a native data type or small class object(buffer) on Ubuntu.

Comment: You proooobably shouldn't be using Linux for anything "extremely time-critical"...

Comment: @AKX The word atomic from your comment was very helpful. :) Well 'extreme' is a quite relative expression. I thought it is a level worth trying with Linux utilizing RTOS and process core designation in a multicore processor. If fails, I go with FPGA.

Comment: Linux isn't an RTOS (it gets closer with the PREEMPT_RT patch). You might not need an FPGA either – maybe look at the devices that can run FreeRTOS? https://www.freertos.org/RTOS_ports.html

Comment: @AKX I am trying to use it as RTOS with Xenomai, though still, it is not real-time in a strict manner. I appreciate your kind advice.

Comment: As a general principle, you need a mutex unless, using explicit atomicity and memory ordering rules of your machine architecture and/or high level language, you can prove that you don't need it.  Typical problems you may otherwise encounter: writing process caches data in registers instead of writing to memory when you wanted, reader sees partial updates that are inconsistent, reader sees updates out of order.

Comment: It is certainly not the case that the reader process will automatically wait until the writer is done writing.  There is not even any way for any part of the machine to know whether the writer is "done" or whether it intends to write some more data.